# I want to use jquery to make the option value element able to show some stuff and exclude other

Tags: html

I try to show some portfolio stuff by using the select attribute, but nothing happens. Basically, it is sorting and displaying.

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="selection">
        <span>Projets: </span>
        <select name="" id="options">
            <option class="option" value="1" data-filter="all">All</option>
            <option class="option" value="2" data-filter="blab">blab</option>
            <option class="option" value="3" data-filter="blob">blob</option>
            <option class="option" value="4" data-filter="blib">blib</option>
            <option class="option" value="5" data-filter="bleb">bleb</option>
            <option class="option" value="6" data-filter="bldb">bldb</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="box filter website">Website</div>
<div class="box filter graphics">Graphics</div>
<div class="box filter psd">PSD</div>
<div class="box filter logo">Logo</div>
<div class="box filter application">Application</div>        
<div class="box filter website">Website</div>
<div class="box filter graphics">Graphics</div>
<div class="box filter psd">PSD</div>
<div class="box filter logo">Logo</div>
<div class="box filter application">Application</div>        
    <div class="box filter website">Website</div>
    <div class="box filter graphics">Graphics</div>
    <div class="box filter psd">PSD</div>
    <div class="box filter logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="box filter application">Application</div>
    <div class="box filter psd">PSD</div>
```

The jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("selection").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr("data-filter");

            if(value == "all"){
                $(".option").show("1000");
            }
            else {
                $(".option").not("."+value).hide("1000");
                $(".option").filter("."+value).show("1000");
            }
        })    
    });
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,
C.

Comment: `$(".option").show("1000");`     ?

Answer (score 0):

`selection`  is div and click event will be fired when it is clicked, better option is to implement change event of

in your `var value = $(this).attr("data-filter");` syntax `this` will be div element which has not attribute which you need

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you can get value of selected option like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#options").change(function(){
            var value = $("#options").find(":selected");
            value = value.attr("data-filter");
            if(value == "all"){
                // Do Your Stuff
            }
            else {
                // Do Your Stuff
            }
        })    
    });
```